# How to pass slicer range to groupby value

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, slicers

I want to find the sum of values groupby name according to time slicer visual in the powerBI
How can I achieve this?

```
name    date          value
Kelvin  10/01/1989     3
Peter   02/05/2018     4
Kelvin  02/02/2012     5
James   02/07/2014     2
Peter   04/01/2012     2
```

Comment: Have you tried to, I don't know, create a visual and a slicer? Because, assuming you have your data types correct (value as a number, date as a date), thats exactly what will powerbi do for you automatically. Just put your columns onto the canvas and see what happens.

Comment: I have received The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value. error when I tried to use groupby and sumx(currentgroup()) combination.

Comment: You are trying to create a column or metric, which you need not do. All you need is to take your columns and drag them into a single visual.